# Trying to duplicate a table without data

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have a table which I would like to duplicate without any data in it (Only the columns).
So I have 2 types of databases, Oracle and Sql Server.

I have constructed this:

```
CREATE TABLE TMPTABLE AS SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE 1 = 0
```

It works fine in the Oracle database, but in the Sql Server I get this error:

```
Error Number:156,State:1,Class:15 Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'SELECT'.
```

Sql Server version: 14.0.1000.169.

Comment: That's not a MySQL version number. The current version of MySQL is 8.x, there's no MySQL 14.

Comment: In most databases you can use `CREATE TABLE newTable LIKE oldTable;`

Comment: Have you read the documentation whether MySQL can do `CREATE TABLE ... SELECT` or not?

Comment: @Eric MySQL definitely can do that, I've used it many times. But he's apparently not using MySQL -- that's not a MySQL error message or version number.

Comment: The given query [works in MySQL](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/gpwh9Cn9TZmCGuMeqHhoQZ/0)

Comment: That's a version number for SQL-Server 2017.

Comment: Sorry, my bad, Sql Server, not MySql.

Comment: You can try `SELECT * INTO TMPTABLEFORUSERSUPDATING FROM WUSER WHERE 1 = 0`

Comment: @Eric Perfect, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
CREATE TABLE newtable SELECT * FROM oldtable
```

Without AS

Comment: Error Number:156,State:1,Class:15 Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'SELECT'.

Comment: CREATE TABLE new_tbl LIKE orig_tbl;

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-like.html

Comment: The problem was already solved + I'm not using MySql.